# Allow access to S3 bucket via VPC or via console?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want my S3 bucket to be accessible in two ways:

- Via the console when I'm logged in, so I can modify files
- Via EC2 instances in a certain VPC (IAM roles are set up correctly for this)

Here's the bucket policy I'm using:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1415115909152",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Principal-Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "CanonicalUser": "<my c_id>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-keys",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-keys/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-keys",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-keys/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-<my_vpce_id>"
                }
            },
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works for access from the VPC, but not for me logged in at the console. Obviously I can remove the bucket policy, make changes, then reapply it, but I'd rather not...

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific user setup for console access? If your session is not using the CanonicalUser then it will likely have no access.

Comment: Yes it's a specific user, I grabbed the token from my security credentials in the console while logged in.